# Block form of link_to removes href

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Why would this method in my application helper return invisible in the view?

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  d = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'
  link_to(title, sort: column, direction: d) do
    content_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-#{sort_direction}")
  end
end
```

If the `link_to` *isn't* nested with the icon class in it it works fine, i.e., this works great:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  d = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'
  link_to(title, sort: column, direction: d)
end
```

What do I have to do to get the icon to display? It shows up in the source code fine...

[image: invisible]

It just leaves a blank cell in the table. Any ideas?

**Update**

It seems like the block form of `link_to`removes `href` from `a`. See screenshot above and compare with this:

[image: what the hell]

What's going on?

Here's a call to `sortable`:

```
<th><%= sortable 'client_code', 'Client ID' %></th>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of a call to `sortable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fa-asc` doesn't exist, hence the blank cell. You should be using `fa-sort-asc` (see the [Font Awesome icon set](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)).

---

Concerning your update, `link_to`'s first argument is the *url*, whereas you are passing it the *title* as a string (see [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)). Try something like this:

```
link_to(users_path, sort: column, direction: d) do
  (title + ' ' + content_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-sort-#{sort_direction}")).html_safe
end
```

Note that you have to concatenate the *title* because when using `link_to` as a block the entire body is defined by the block. You also need to use `html_safe` in order for it to output correctly.

Comment: That makes the icons work (my bad there) but the block form of `link_to` removes `href` from `a` (see above) which seems wrong.

Comment: Both answers fixed my problem, but since this mentions the `fa-asc` mistake too I'll stick with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when given a block, `link_to` has the following signature(s)

```
link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end

link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

so in your call it looks like it would be picking the latter version ( `url, html_options`).

The problem is you are not passing in the url at all, So if you look it is making the href your `title` of client_id.

Since you cannot easily pass in the url, and the required options while using the block form,  (looks like your following a railscast?)

perhaps something like this.

make a glyph helper.. (I put this as an application Helper)

```
def glyph(*names)
  classes = names.map{|name| "fa-#{name.to_s.gsub('_','-')}" }.unshift 'fa'
  content_tag :i, nil, class: classes
end
```

and then use that to add the glyph to the title call and get rid of the block..

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  d = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'
  link_to (title + glyph("sort-#{sort_direction}") ).html_safe, sort: column, direction: d
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, but this still returns the icon and no title.

Comment: Ahh the problem is that ` sort: column, direction: d` are actually options that need to be fed to the url_helper to generate the url, and not the html_options. ...